# Getting max count for multiple different types SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to run the following query: for each type of video game, print the year which produced the most games of that type. I have two tables:

Games: id, name, year

Game_Types: game_id, type

Games looks like this:

```
id name        year
1  The First   2005
2  The Second  2006
3  The Third   2005
4  Fourth      2008
5  Sweetness   2008
```

Game_Types looks like this:

```
game_id  type
1        action
2        fps
3        animated
3        action
4        stealth
5        stealth
5        action
```

So far, I have a query that produces the max number produced for each genre, which is as follows:

```
SELECT TYPE, max(cnt)
FROM (
  SELECT GT.GENRE, G.YEAR, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM GAMES G, GAME_TYPES GT
  WHERE G.ID = GT.GAME_ID
  GROUP BY GT.TYPE, G.YEAR
)
GROUP BY TYPE;
```

However, this produces a table like the following:

```
TYPE     MAX(cnt)
Animated 42
Mystery  58
```

I can't figure out how to incorporate the year into the results and remove the max(cnt) from my select. I tried what is below, but that doesn't work.

```
SELECT TYPE, YEAR, max(cnt)
FROM (
  SELECT GT.GENRE, G.YEAR, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM GAMES G, GAME_TYPES GT
  WHERE G.ID = GT.GAME_ID
  GROUP BY GT.TYPE, G.YEAR
)
GROUP BY TYPE;
```

I feel like I'm missing some simple thought process, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a small sample of rows from the two tables involved?

Comment: And given that you have `GROUP BY GENRE` on these when it doesn't appear in `SELECT` I'm going to assume you are using MySQL here and not Oracle - is that correct?

Comment: Using oracle as the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` for this purpose:

```
SELECT GENRE, YEAR, CNT
FROM (SELECT GT.GENRE, G.YEAR, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GT.GENRE ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM GAMES G JOIN
           GAME_TYPES GT
           ON G.ID = GT.GAME_ID
      GROUP BY GT.GENRE, G.YEAR
)
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: That definitely works. Could you explain exactly what the row_number is doing here? Also, is it possible to write the query without using row_number?

Comment: `row_number()` is an analytic function:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm.

Comment: This is correct for my purposes, but just want to make a note that the query above only works if there are no ties with count. If a type has multiple years where the most were produced, then this query fails to list them all.

Comment: @thehandyman . . . That is fixed by using `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.  Your question says "print the **year** . . ." (my emphasis), so I thought you only wanted one when there were ties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

select type,year from
(select type,year,count(games.id) as cnt from games,game_types 
where id=game_id group by year,type)
as a group by type having max(cnt)

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Add a provides a alias 'a' for subquery you can use it or remove it , its up to you.Do remove it and give a try.

Comment: it's the "as" before the table alias that's causing the problem; remove that and it should work fine.

Comment: The 'as cnt'  is compulsory part as it provides a alias for the count and it is a rule that 2 aggregate functions cannot be used together adjacent. Hence we will have to give that alias in order to make the query run. The problem is being made by the 'as a' it is alias for subquery and is supported by some versions and not by some. Hence remove it and the query shall work.